# using _open and _setmode in visual studio 2015 on windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, crt

I'm trying to use the functions _open and _setmode from `IO.h` but can't seem to compile. I'm getting the following error:

error C3861: '_lsetmode': identifier not found

error C2065: '_open': undeclared identifier

What do I need to do to make sure I'm pointing to these functions?

Comment: Ah, I found the issue it was a conflicting include with another IO.h that is in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue it was a conflicting include with another IO.h that is in my project.